# overwrite existing record, if a match is found from comparing two columns in different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

***EDIT**
I changed  and improve my question. I have two worksheets in a workbook.

Master Sheet

```
  C        D    E
  Apple   100    No
  Banana  85    Yes
  Lemon   11    Yes
  Kiwi    165    No
```

Update Sheet

```
  C        D    E
  Apple    34   Yes
  Kiwi    165   Yes
```

I want to update the record in Master sheet from the Update sheet, so after the update the records in Master sheet will look like this

Master Sheet

```
  C        D    E
  Apple   34    Yes
  Banana  85    Yes
  Lemon   11    Yes
  Kiwi    165   Yes
```

Example, a comparison will be done based on column C in both Master and Update sheet, if a match is found, it will overwrite the entire row in Master sheet. I had written a portion of the code, and I seem to be stuck in how to overwrite the entire row.

```
Sub fruitUpdate()

Dim rangeUpdt, rangeMstr As Range

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Master")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Fruit Update")

On Error Resume Next
With ws1
    Set rangeMstr = .Range("C4", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'records start at C4
End With
With ws2
    Set rangeUpdt = .Range("C10", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'records start at C10
End With
    If rangeMstr = rangeUpdt Then
    'overwrite, copy to masterlist (here's the part that I stuck)
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to achieve it by using excel vba. I thinking of using copy.Destination method, but I think it will insert as new data instead or overwriting it. I am new to VBA, any helps are much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? (See "[ask]" and the [help/on-topic] as well as this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).)

Comment: Is there a column or combination of columns which uniquely identify a single record?

Comment: hi @TimWilliams my idea is that, i want to compare value in column c which is the username (both sheets have the column C as username). If the username is match, it will update the existing record for the selected user from "NO" to "YES".

Comment: Loop over the edited rows, find the value in ColC on Sheet5, then update the No to Yes on that row.  You can use Find() or Match() (for example) to locate the row.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I've updated my question. thank you